# firebird c# connect to a remote db

Tags: c#, firebird

I am working on some existing project and I am trying to make it go from many firebird databases on the client end to one server based database.

Unfortunately I am having some trouble with the connection string.

Is it possible to connect to a .fdb file on a remote server?

Currently the code is as follows:

```
var builder = new FbConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Database = @"C:\test.db",
            ServerType = FbServerType.Embedded,
            Pooling = isPooled
        };
```

I have read some examples about how it can be done like the below but its not working:

```
FbConnectionStringBuilder(@"Database=192.168.1.235:C:\share\test.fdb;User ID=sysdba;Password=masterkey;")
```

It still connects to just the local directory C:\share\test.fdb. As that is not my ip address. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Database` property is only for the database filename or alias, you need to use `DataSource` for the hostname or IP address and `Port` for the Firebird port.
Check out [.NET — Examples of use](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-examples-of-use/) and [Connection string parameters](http://web.firebirdsql.org/firebirdtutorial/connection-string-parameters.html)

Also the class [`FbConnectionStringBuilder`](http://web.firebirdsql.org/firebirdtutorial/fbconnectionstringbuilder.html) is intended to simplify building a connection string (it has properties for the various connection string properties), so your first use is correct, but the second use is a bit odd.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think I worked it out. You cannot access an embedded database remotely. So once the server software was installed and this was removed it all worked fine. Would be a handy feature to connect to it on a remote drive but ohh well.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure fireBird is listening on port 3050, 
uncomment this lines in `firebird.conf`

```
RemoteServiceName=gds_db
RemoteServicePort=3050
```

restart the service.